# BottomNavigationView Back button not working properly

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

When is press back button my fragment is changing to home page, but bottom icon is not changing. I posted my all code here. If i select more then two navigation button from bottom navigation view items then when i press back button it'll redirect to last selected button item.

But now what happening is that suppose i'm on the last item say 'Notification' [as you can see in screenshot], now when i press back button it'll directly take me to 'Home' button, but what i want is that it should take me first to 'Search' button item and then to 'Home' not directly to 'home'.

How can i achieve this??

Here is the layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/activity_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context="com.segunfamisa.sample.bottomnav.MainActivity">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#f1f1f1">

                </FrameLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/navigation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String SELECTED_ITEM = "arg_selected_item";

    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNav;
    private int mSelectedItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                selectFragment(item);
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItem selectedItem;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSelectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, 0);
            selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(mSelectedItem);
        } else
        {
            selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
        }

        selectFragment(selectedItem);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, mSelectedItem);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        MenuItem homeItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);

        if (mSelectedItem != homeItem.getItemId()) {
            // select home item
           // homeItem.setCheckable(true);

            Log.d("backpressids","****  "+mSelectedItem);
            selectFragment(homeItem);

        } else {

            super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }

    private void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment frag = null;
        item.setCheckable(true);
        // init corresponding fragment
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_home:

                TabFragmentOne fragmentone = new TabFragmentOne();
                FragmentTransaction ft =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container, fragmentone);
                ft.commit();


                break;
            case R.id.menu_notifications:


                TabFragmentThree fragmentone_Three = new TabFragmentThree();
                FragmentTransaction ft_three =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft_three.replace(R.id.container, fragmentone_Three);
                ft_three.commit();

                break;
            case R.id.menu_search:


                TabFragmentTwo tabFragmentTwo = new TabFragmentTwo();
                FragmentTransaction ft_two =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft_two.replace(R.id.container,tabFragmentTwo);
                ft_two.commit();


                break;
        }

        // update selected item
        mSelectedItem = item.getItemId();


        updateToolbarText(item.getTitle());

        if (frag != null) {
            TabFragmentOne fragmentone = new TabFragmentOne();
            FragmentTransaction ft =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragmentone);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    private void updateToolbarText(CharSequence text) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(text);
        }
    }


}
```

please help me any one.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(ITEM_ID)` to select desired `MenuItem`:

In `onBackPressed()`, use `mBottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.menu_home)` or `mBottomNav.setSelectedItemId(homeItem.getItemId())`.

**Update `onBackPressed()` method as below:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    MenuItem homeItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);

    if (mSelectedItem != homeItem.getItemId()) {

        selectFragment(homeItem);

        // Select home item
        mBottomNav.setSelectedItemId(homeItem.getItemId());
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks for help and it's working perfectly.
But i updated my question can you please help me with that?

Comment: I will.... but please do not try to modify original question after getting expected answer. It will make confusion for other users. Its better to post another question with your new requirements. Hope you understand :)

Comment: You can use switchcase of if-else condition in your onBackPressed. Like if(mSelectedItem == R.id.menu_notifications) then show search..... else if(mSelectedItem == R.id.menu_search) then show home...

Comment: i tried but not working..can you please help me little more.

Comment: can you please post another question about it??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362819/on-back-press-traversing-through-last-two-tabs-not-working-properly-in-bottomnav

Comment: I have posted the another question on the same topic. Please refer it and go through the code snippet. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go back to all the items on the stack (not only home), try the following code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
if (!isFirstFragment) {
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
}
transaction.commit();
```

Then, add this code onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        int index = ((getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()) -1);
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(index);
        int stackId = backEntry.getId();
        mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(stackId).setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have more than one fragment under one bottom navigation item, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution. I just added a counter `checkBackSteck`

binding.bnb - this is `buttonNavigationView`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private val checkBackStack = ArrayList<Int>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    checkBackStack.add(0)
    val mainFragment = MainFragment()
    val libraryFragment = LibraryFragment()
    val menuFragment = MenuFragment()
    val statisticFragment = StatisticFragment()
    val profileFragment = ProfileFragment()

    binding.apply {
        bnb.setOnItemSelectedListener {

            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.bnb_home -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_in, R.anim.fragment_out)
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, mainFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit()
                    checkBackStack.add(0)
                    true
                }
                R.id.bnb_library -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_in, R.anim.fragment_out)
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, libraryFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit()
                    checkBackStack.add(1)
                    true
                }
                R.id.bnb_menu ->{
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_in, R.anim.fragment_out)
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, menuFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit()
                    checkBackStack.add(2)
                    true
                }
                R.id.bnb_statistic -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_in, R.anim.fragment_out)
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, statisticFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit()
                    checkBackStack.add(3)
                    true
                }
                R.id.bnb_profile -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_in, R.anim.fragment_out)
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, profileFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit()
                    checkBackStack.add(4)
                    true
                }

                else -> false
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (checkBackStack.size == 1){
        super.onBackPressed()
    } else {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        binding.bnb.menu.getItem(checkBackStack.get(checkBackStack.count() - 2)).isChecked = true
        checkBackStack.removeAt(checkBackStack.count() - 1)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add some more description of what does your code do